# Oracle BI Publisher does not locate file path

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee, bi-publisher

I have a CSV file located on my C drive:

[Files on my C: drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb2NW.png)

I have set up a connection from my Oracle BI Publisher reporting tool to this local csv file:

[Setting up connection to CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H33AD.png)

Then when trying to create a data model from the connection, using the CSV option, I get an error message saying that the file is not found:

[Trying to connect to file from connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFdWZ.png)

I really don't know what I am doing wrong here. Any help please

I am connected with an admin role.

Comment: Hi there - please replace your code as text as opposed to using images as code cannot be copied and pasted, image links can break, screen readers  can’t read the code etc.

Comment: is it the client C drive or the server C drive ?

Answer (score 0):

The last picture  shows that you didn't upload the file. You were trying to connect to a Data source instead.
If you want  to work with the data in a csv file from your local disk you have to choose option **"Local"** on that screen. Just below "Local" there is a **"File name"** text followed by an **upload button**. Press that button and then another screen shall open where you can explore your local disk and choose the file for upload. Regards...